# What is the error in this simple function returning pointer?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

In this problem statement, we have to take an array of numbers from the user, then ask for a number they want to search for and give address of it. I have written the following code but having constant error.
How to resolve it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int search(int ,int ,int );
main()
{
   int i,a[i],target,*p,n;
   pritnf("enter number of numbers u want");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   printf("enter numbers you want in array");
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       scanf("%d",&a[i]);
   }
   printf("enter the number u are searching");
   scanf("%d",&target);
   p=search(a,n,target);
   if(p==NULL)
   {
       printf("target not found");
   }
   else
   {
       printf("target found at %d",p);
   }
}
int search(int a[],int n,int target)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==target)
        {
            return &a[i];

        }

    }
}
```

ERROR:
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Untitled1.c|26|error: conflicting types for 'search'|

Comment: Just define `search` before `main()`. Your declaration does not match your definition. As a note, it's not worth omitting the variable names, especially when you slip and drop important type information like `a[]`. Just copy that line if you must, keep it exactly the same.

Comment: I'm not sure if you really want to return an address (i.e. a pointer). It seems more reasonable to return an index, in which case `return &a[i];` can be replaced with `return i;`.

Comment: Your function doesn't return a value if the target isn't found.

Comment: In `main`, the array `int a[i]` is being defined with an undefined length `i`. You really want the array to be defined with length `n` *after* the desired value of `n` has been read in.

Answer (score 2):

You declared the function as `int search(int ,int ,int );`, with *3 integer parameters*, but the definition presents **a pointer to integer** (`int a[]` equals to `int* a`) and *2 integer parameters*.

The function declaration should be `int search(int* ,int ,int );`

---

However, your code presents many other problems:

- it's a good practice to define the main function as `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, making it return an integer value (usually **0** for *success* and **positive or negative values** for *failure*). You might find the following post interesting: [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/204483/19544859);
- the first `printf()` is spelled wrong: "printnf", which generates an *implicit declaration warning*, and since a function called printnf isn't declared anywhere, the compilation fails;
- you're assigning the integer returning value of `search()` to `p`, which is a variable of type "pointer to integer", which generates an "implicit int conversion warning";
- your search function should just return `a[i]`, while currently it's returning `&a[i]` which is a pointer to integer. That generates an "implicit int conversion warning" too;
- the ones outlined by [Haris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75287765/19544859) in the other answer.

I'd suggest you to turn on the compiler warnings and pay extreme attention to what it tells you, since all those problems could be easily avoided by taking a look at them.

Answer (score 2):

```
int search(int ,int ,int );
```

Your declaration

```
int search(int a[],int n,int target)
```

does not match your definition. Hence the error.

Either fix that, or define the function before `main()`. That way there would be no need of any prototypes.

You are also defining the array in `main()` with an undefined variable. Here:

```
int i,a[i];
```

the value of `i` is indeterminate. Declare the array once you've read the input.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the very beginning.

The header `<conio.h>` is not a standard header and neither declaration from the header is used in the program. So this directive

```
#include<conio.h>
```

may be removed.

The function `search` is declared with three parameters of the type `int`

```
int search(int ,int ,int );
```

That is it does not accept an array.

And the return type of the function is again `int` instead of a pointer type.

Pay attention to that the function will not change a passed array. So the function declaration will look like

```
 int * search( const int[] ,size_t , int );
```

The second parameter that specifies the number of elements in the passed array has the unsigned integer type `size_t` instead of the signed integer type `int`. That is the number of elements in an array can not be a negative value. So there is no sense to declare this parameter as having a signed integer type.

Also your function returns nothing if the target element is not found in the array.

In this declaration

```
int i,a[i],target,*p,n;
```

you declared a variable length array `a[i]`. But the variable `i` has not initialized yet. So this declaration is invalid and results in undefined behavior.

And moreover the number of elements in the array is stored in the variable `n`:

```
pritnf("enter number of numbers u want");
scanf("%d",&n);
```

So you need to declare the array after the variable `n` will get its value.

In this call of `printf`

```
printf("target found at %d",p);
```

there is used invalid conversion specifier `%d` with a pointer. This invokes undefined behavior.

You need to use at least the conversion specifier `%p` instead of `%d`.

And at last the function `main` shall have the return type `int`.

```
int main( void )
```

The program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * search( const int[], size_t, int );

int main( void )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    pritnf( "enter number of numbers u want: " );
   
    if ( scanf( "%zu", &n ) == 1 && n != 0 )
    {
        int a[n]; 
        int target = 0;
        int *p = NULL;

        printf( "enter numbers you want in array\n" );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            scanf( "%d", a + i );
        }

        printf( "enter the number u are searching: " );
        
        scanf( "%d", &target );

        p = search( a, n, target );

        if ( p == NULL )
        {
            printf( "target not found\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "target found at %p\n", ( void * )p );
        }
    }
}

int * search( const int a[], size_t n, int target )
{
    const int *p = NULL;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        p = a;

        while ( p != a + n && *p != target ) ++p;

        if ( p == a + n ) p = NULL;
    }

    return ( int * )p;
}
```